# Generic extension method to convert from one collection to another

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working in a code base which has a lot of first class collections.

In order to ease using these collections with LINQ, there is an extension method per collection that looks like:

```
public static class CustomCollectionExtensions
{
    public static CustomCollection ToCustomCollection(this IEnumerable<CustomItem> enumerable)
    {
        return new CustomCollection(enumerable);
    }
}
```

With the accompanying constructors:

```
public class CustomCollection : List<CustomItem>
{
    public CustomCollection(IEnumerable<CustomItem> enumerable) : base(enumerable) { }
}
```

This winds up being a bunch of boilerplate so I attempted to write a generic `IEnumerable<U>.To<T>()` so that we wouldn't have to keep generating these specific ToXCollection() methods.

I got as far as:

```
public static class GenericCollectionExtensions
{
    public static T To<T, U>(this IEnumerable<U> enumerable) where T : ICollection<U>, new()
    {
        T collection = new T();
        foreach (U u in enumerable)
        {
            collection.Add(u);
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Which has to be called like `customCollectionInstance.OrderBy(i => i.Property).To<CustomCollection, CustomItem>()`

Is there a way to avoid having to specify the `CustomItem` type so we can instead use `customCollectionInstance.OrderBy(i => i.Property).To<CustomCollection>()` or is this not something that can be done generically?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not.

Comment: Why exactly do you have so many different collections? That looks like code smell to me.

Comment: @svick - there are a lot of collections because it's a large code base and first class collections were/are favored over generic object collections to have somewhere to encapsulate set based rules rather than defining them relative to generic IWhatever<DomainObject>. I'm not sure if that was a good or bad decision, but I do know that `var a = Member.Offers.ActiveOffers()` looks a bit cleaner than having to use a .Where() every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something close to what you want:

```
public static class GenericCollectionExtensions
{
    public sealed class CollectionConverter<TItem>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<TItem> _source;

        public CollectionConverter(IEnumerable<TItem> source)
        {
            _source = source;
        }

        public TCollection To<TCollection>()
            where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>, new()
        {
            var collection = new TCollection();
            foreach(var item in _source)
            {
                collection.Add(item);
            }
            return collection;
        }
    }

    public static CollectionConverter<T> Convert<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        return new CollectionConverter<T>(sequence);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
customCollectionInstance.OrderBy(i => i.Property).Convert().To<CustomCollection>();
```